# React Native ECMAScript 6 Object syntax only has key, no explicit value?

Tags: javascript, facebook, react-native, ecmascript-6

The code below is from [React Native tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-text-input.html#content)
Cause i'm JS noob, I'm curious about：
1. why 
`(text) => this.setState({text})` can assign input value text to key text of object `this.state` ?
I'm much familiar to write it with `(text) => this.setState({'text':text})`
2. is type of `{key}` the same with `{key:value}` ? Are they all Object?

```js
class PizzaTranslator extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: ''};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{padding: 10}}>
        <TextInput
          style={{height: 40}}
          placeholder="Type here to translate!"

          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}      
       />
        <Text style={{padding: 10, fontSize: 42}}>
          {this.state.text.split(' ').map((word) => word && '').join(' ')}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's just a shortcut, it means the same thing. `{key} === {key: key}`

Comment: thanks a lot for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual answer is just i would say that:

```
{key} === {key:key}
```

As the a single var passed in the object is treated as key:value both are same. so that would be something like :

```
{"key":"key"}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for helping